# UIScrollView's last lines in subview is visible but not touchable

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, subview, modalviewcontroller

I create a view (main view) that contains number of another views (widgets). That main view shows perfect. Main view can resize while running so I added it to a UIScrollView.

Problem is that the scroll view's subview (witch is main view) now visible correctly but last main view's widget can't be touched (there is a button and I can't push it).

Problem appears only in landscape orientation. In a portrait orientation it works just fine.

Problem disappears if set last widget frame height bigger that it actually is (actual height is 41 and it starts work if I set 41+50).

Heven't any clue why this happens. Thanks a lot for any help.

P.S. UIScrollView with its content is in modal window.

UPDATE.
Ok. I used to put my scrollView in UINavigationController and only after in modal window.
I found that if push scrollView directly in modal window (by presentModalViewController: method) problem disappears. But there isn't navigation bar.

What problem can be with UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! Problem was in scrollView itself. After I deselect "Autoresize subviews" property in interphase builder it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and the reason was that the frame of parent view was smaller than the frame of the scrollview.